# Pass in array of certain size to test with xunit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, xunit

I need help with writing unit test with xunit. I am trying to test a validation where array length cannot be greater than 20MB

```
[Theory]
[InlineData((arrayGreaterThan20MB())]
public void Fail_when_documentSize_is_greater(byte[] documentSize)
{
    _getAccountFileViewModel.Content = documentSize;
}
```

Private Function

```
private static byte[] arrayGreaterThan20MB()
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[5000000000];
    return arr;
}
```

I am not sure what is the best way to test this. I am getting a error when I am trying to pass function in inline data.

Error "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Also given the name of the test, how do you plan to assert that the subject fails?

Comment: I see you edited the question to show a larger array, can you please edit the question to show what the error is that you are getting.

Comment: Why not just declare the array within the test itself instead of trying to pass via inline data attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare the array within the test itself, instead of trying to pass via inline data attribute

```
[Theory]
public void Fail_when_documentSize_is_greater() {
    byte[] overSizedDocument =  new byte[5000000000];
    _getAccountFileViewModel.Content = overSizedDocument;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the result of a method call as parameter of an attribute. That's what the error is telling you. You can only pass constants or literals. For example like this:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("a", "b")]
public void InlineDataTest(string first, string second)
{
    Assert.Equal("a", first);
    Assert.Equal("b", second);
}
```

XUnit has some other attributes, that can help you here. E.g. there is the `MemberData` attribute, that allows you to specify a **method name** of a method that provides the test data. Note that it returns an *IEnumerable of object array*. Each object array will be used to call the test method once. The content of the object array are the parameters. For example:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(DataGeneratorMethod))]
public void MemberDataTest(string first, string second)
{
    Assert.Equal("a", first);
    Assert.Equal("b", second);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> DataGeneratorMethod()
{
    var result = new List<object[]>();   // each item of this list will cause a call to your test method
    result.Add(new object[] {"a", "b"}); // "a" and "b" are parameters for one test method call
    return result;

    // or 
    // yield return new object[] {"a", "b"};
}
```

In the case you mentioned above, the simplest way would be just to call your method that creates the test data within your test method.

```
[Theory]
public void Fail_when_documentSize_is_greater()
{
    _getAccountFileViewModel.Content = arrayGreaterThan20MB();
}
```

There is another attribute called `ClassData` that can use a data generator class.
More detailed information can be found on [this blog post](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/)